# Spring boot authorization returns 403 for any authorization request using @RolesAllowed, @Secured or @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, authorization, http-status-code-403

I've been working from this article (and a few other similar ones): https://medium.com/omarelgabrys-blog/microservices-with-spring-boot-authentication-with-jwt-part-3-fafc9d7187e8

The client is an Angular 8 app which acquires a Jwt from an independent microservice.  Trying to add filter(s) to a different microservice to require specific authorization via jwt roles.

Consistently receiving 403 errors.

Security Config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true,
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurityConfig() {}

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to store user's state.
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
                .addFilterAfter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter2(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                // authorization requests config
                .authorizeRequests()
                // Any other request must be authenticated
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

Filter:

```
public class JwtAuthorizationFilter2 extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final String HEADER = "Authorization";
    private final String PREFIX = "Bearer ";
    private final String SECRET = "foo";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String token = request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            DecodedJWT decoded = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC512(SecurityConstants.SECRET.getBytes()))
                    .build()
                    .verify(token.replace(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX, ""));

            String user = decoded.getSubject();
            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> sgas = Arrays.stream(
                    decoded.getClaim("roles").asArray(String.class))
                    .map( s -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(s))
                    .collect( Collectors.toList());
            if (sgas != null) {
                sgas.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("FOO_Admin"));
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        user,
                        null,
                        sgas);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            }
            else {
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine without any authorization requirements defined, but if an authorization is defined in WebSecurityConfig, or by decorating a controller method, http 403 is received for all requests in scope.

Examples:

```
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("FOO_Admin")

// or any of these 
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('FOO_Admin')")
@RolesAllowed({"FOO_Admin"})
@Secured({"FOO_Admin"})
Device get(@PathVariable String id) {
    // some code
}
```

When code is halted at `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth)`,
`auth.authenticated = true`
and 
`auth.authorities` includes a SimpleGrantedAuthority for "FOO_Admin"

So I'm wondering whether:
The FilterChain needs an Authentication Filter (or does authentication occur in JwtAuthorizationFilter2?)?
There is not a spelling or formatting or capitalization difference to role name.

I'm stupefied.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`@PreAuthorize("hasRole('FOO_Admin'))`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#el-common-built-in) expects the user has an authority  `ROLE_FOO_Admin`, which will be prefixed by `ROLE_`. However,  the user only has the authority `FOO_Admin` , hence it fails to access the method.

You have several options:

(1) Change the prefix by declaring a `GrantedAuthorityDefaults` bean:

```java
@Bean
GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
    return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults("FOO");
}
```

And use `@PreAuthorize(hasRole('Admin'))` to secure the method.

(2) Or more simpler is to use `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('FOO_Admin')")` , which will directly check if the user has the authority `FOO_Admin` , without adding any prefix to it.

*P.S `JwtAuthorizationFilter2` only verifies if an user is valid and get the related user information which prepare for the authorization user later. It is an authentication and I would rename it to `JwtAuthenticationFilter2` to describe more exactly what it does actually.*

Comment: This was my problem.  Thank You!  Now to go back and see how I managed to miss this convention....